# Is there a cap to the number of charges a wand or staff can hold?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

For those wand or staffs that have charges, it has an entry that just states the number of charges:

eg. Under the *Wand of Fireballs*

> This wand has 7 Charges

I have just assumed that this is the cap or maximum number of charges a wand can hold.  But that is not explicitly stated.

Then there is the *Staff of the Magi*

> if doing so brings the staff's total number of charges above 50 the staff explodes

which seems like an explicit cap on the number of charges, indicating that at least *SOME* staff's / wands do have a cap.

OK - RAI the listed number probably should be assumed to be the cap.  But is this ever explicitly stated anywhere?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wands and staves can only regain charges up to their listed starting amount.

Each one, such as the *wand of fireballs* ([SRD p. 248-249](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)), notes its number of charges, and that it can "regain expended" charges.  A wand or staff cannot "regain" a charge that it never had to begin with.

The *staff of the magi* ([SRD p. 244-245](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)) is an exception.  It has both a general property to regain charges, just like every other magic wand and staff, but it also has the "Spell Absorption" property which allows it to "[gain] a number of charges".

This Spell Absorption allows it to exceed the starting number of charges, and that would allow it to regain charges to its new maximum, if it didn't destroy itself upon exceeding its initial amount of charges.  But it does, explosively.

Comment: "Regain expended".  Its obvious now that you point it out.  Thanks.